# Selenium youtube comment bot, unable to find youtube comment box

Tags: python, selenium

I officially need help.

Below is the full code for you tube log in, using selenium `.find_element` methods

navigating to specific videos, scrolling down and trying to select a youtube comment box. I have tried all the selenium methods to find a comment box and click on it ( i wont list all of them) without success.

Can someone please let me know what could be wrong. Considering that I have successfully logged in to the you tube using selenium methods, I dont see a reason why the same shouldn't work for finding a you tube comment box.

```
import time
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


def youtube_login():

    email = 'email@gmail.com'
    password = 'password'

    comment = 'We are looking for good people/traders like yourself to join a new trading chatroom. Chatroom has a multi asset live squawk news, economic events notifications and soon live trade callouts and trade stream. For now the main focus is bond futures but all asset classes are welcome. If you are interested please join while its still free https://discord.gg/ssDvDnx?'

        # Browser
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Fhl%3Den%26feature%3Dsign_in_button%26app%3Ddesktop%26action_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26next%3D%252F&uilel=3&passive=true&service=youtube#identifier')
    #driver.maximize_window()

        # log in
    driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId').send_keys(email)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('CwaK9').click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 500).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password")))
    driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 500).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "CwaK9")))
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('CwaK9').click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 500).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "identity-prompt-confirm-button")))
    driver.find_element_by_id('identity-prompt-confirm-button').click()


    urls = []

    # You can add in a file and import from there

    inp = open ("urls.txt","r")
    for line in inp.readlines():
        urls.append(line.strip())
        inp.close()

    for url in urls:  
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
        # Scroll, wait for load comment box
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 500);")

        # Lets wait for comment box
        box = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "emoji")))

        # Activate box for comments
        box.click()

        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        driver.find_element_by_id("emoji").send_keys(comment)



youtube_login()
```

Comment: try to trigger the comment box, click on element with id 'placeholder-area', then the emoji input is present.

Comment: yep, you are correct, thank you... next issue .send_keys('comment') :/... I dont understand why the same approach with google LogIn doesnt work with youtube comment box....

NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: [id="labelAndInputContainer"]

PS i tried a bunch of other IDs and Class_names including placeholder-area

Comment: i did not get for which page you are referring  element 'labelAndInputContainer'

Comment: sorry, I wasnt very clear.... to trigger the comment box I used the `id 'place holder'` like you said. My next issue is inputting the comment once the comment box is triggered (last line in the code above). I assumed I should `driver.find_element_by_id("place holder").send_keys(comment)` but I get an error `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: id 'contenteditable-textarea' try sendKeys to that element, if its not working just do js execution of code document.getElementById('contenteditable-textarea').innerHTML = 'your comment text here'

Comment: you sir are a genius, thank you so much, I have been struggling with this the whole day

Comment: you are welcome, i have added it as answer to help other in need. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger comment box click on element with id '**placeholder-area**' then the emoji input will be present.

After that use the input with id '**contenteditable-textarea**' to sendKeys('comment text'), if this does not work send executable script from the driver:

> document.getElementById('contenteditable-textarea').innerHTML = 'your
>   comment text here'

Answer (score 2):

Add this lines

```
 #Activate the box
 commentBox = driver.find_element_by_id('placeholder-area')
 commentBox.click()
 time.sleep(4)

 #Send the keys to the input field
 inputBox =driver.find_element_by_id('contenteditable-root')
 inputBox.send_keys('test')
```

It's working for me in 2020 :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit late but why don't you just go into random videos like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        recently = chrome_browser.find_element_by_xpath('//yt-formatted-string[@title="Recently uploaded"]')
        recently.click()
        break
    except:
        continue
time.sleep(10)
video = chrome_browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="style-scope ytd-rich-item-renderer"]')
video.click()
```